# Memory leak when running universal-sentence-encoder-large itterating on dataframe

Tags: tensorflow, keras-layer, tf.keras, tensorflow-hub

I have 140K sentences I want to get embeddings for. I am using TF_HUB Universal Sentence Encoder and am iterating over the sentences(I know it's not the best way but when I try to feed over 500 sentences into the model it crashes). 
My Environment is:
Ubuntu 18.04
Python 3.7.4
TF 1.14
Ram: 16gb
processor: i-5

my code is:

**version 1**
I iterate inside the tf.session context manager

```py
embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3")
    df = pandas_repository.get_dataframe_from_table('sentences')
    with tf.compat.v1.Session() as session:
        session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        session.run(tf.tables_initializer())
        sentence_embedding = None
        for i, row in df.iterrows():
            sentence = row['content']
            embeddings = embed([sentence])
            sentence_embedding = session.run(embeddings)
            df.at[i, 'embedding'] = sentence_embedding
            print('processed index:', i)
```

**version 2**
I open and close a session within each iteration

```py
embed = hub.Module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3")
    df = pandas_repository.get_dataframe_from_table('sentences')
    for i, row in df.iterrows():
        sentence = row['content']
        embeddings = embed([sentence])
        sentence_embedding = None
        with tf.compat.v1.Session() as session:
            session.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
            session.run(tf.tables_initializer())
            sentence_embedding = session.run(embeddings)
            df.at[i, 'embedding'] = sentence_embedding
            print('processed index:', i)
```

While **version 2** does seem to have some sort of GC and memory is cleared a bit. It still goes over 50 items and explodes.

**version 1** just goes on gobbling memory.

**The correct solution as given by [arnoegw](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7061249/arnoegw)**

```py
def calculate_embeddings(dataframe, table_name):
    sql_get_sentences = "SELECT * FROM semantic_similarity.sentences WHERE embedding IS NULL LIMIT 1500"
    sql_update = 'UPDATE {} SET embedding = data.embedding FROM (VALUES %s) AS data(id, embedding) WHERE {}.id = data.id'.format(table_name, table_name)
    df = pandas_repository.get_dataframe_from_sql(sql_get_sentences) 
    with hub.eval_function_for_module("https://tfhub.dev/google/universal-sentence-encoder-large/3") as embed:    
        while len(df) >= 0:
            sentence_array = df['content'].values
            sentence_embeddings = embed(sentence_array)
            df['embedding'] = sentence_embeddings.tolist()
            values = [tuple(x) for x in df[['id', 'embedding']].values]
            pandas_repository.update_db_from_df('semantic_similarity.sentences', sql_update, values)       
            df = pandas_repository.get_dataframe_from_sql(sql_get_sentences)
```

I am a newbee to TF and can use any help I can get.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code uses tf.Session, so it falls under the TF1.x programming model of first building a dataflow graph and then running it repeatedly with inputs being fed and outputs being fetched from the graph.

But your code does not align well with that programming model. Both versions keep adding new applications of (calls to) the hub.Module to the default TensorFlow graph instead of applying it once and running the same graph repeatedly for the various inputs. Version 2 keeps going into and out of tf.Sessions, which frees some memory but is very inefficient.

Please see my answer to "[Strongly increasing memory consumption when using ELMo from Tensorflow-Hub](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56488857/strongly-increasing-memory-consumption-when-using-elmo-from-tensorflow-hub/56493291#56493291)" for guidance how to do it right in the graph-based programming model of TensorFlow 1.x.

TensorFlow 2.0, which is going to be released soon, defaults to the programming model of "eager execution", which does away with graphs and sessions and would have avoided this confusion. TensorFlow Hub will be updated in due course for TF2.0. For a preview close to your use-case, see https://colab.research.google.com/github/tensorflow/hub/blob/master/examples/colab/tf2_text_classification.ipynb

Comment: with TF2.0, I am facing this issue of crash while getting embeddings in a loop. Do you know solution to this issue in TF2.0 environment.